# Do hats work properly via the app?

Tags: bug

I have installed SoClient via Google Play.

I searched yesterday and voted on good questions 7 times via the app, but nothing happened.

Do hats work properly via the app?

Comment: Not a duplicate; they're using an unofficial client app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"[SoClient](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sudosaints.stackoverflow)" is not the official Stack Exchange app. You should use the [official Stack Exchange app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin)
instead.
The "Cutting the Cord" hat, that you get for voting 7 times via the app, is obtained only by voting via the official app.

Comment: Strange, but search works properly. Ok, Thank you.

Comment: I have install official app, but voting does not work yet. I have voteup 7 times for good questions